# Find whether the following is an inner product

Tags: linear-algebra

> Consider the base $(e_1,e_2,e_3)$ of the vector space $\mathbb{R}^3$
>   and the application $(-|-):\mathbb{R}^3\times\mathbb{R}^3\rightarrow
> > \mathbb{R}$ given by:
>
> $$(x|y):= 2x_1y_1+x_2y_2-x_2y_3-x_3y_2+3x_3y_3$$
>
> $x = x_1e_1+x_2e_2+x_3e_3$ $y = y_1e_1+y_2e_2+y_3e_3$
>
> Show whether this is an internal product.

I think that I have to show if [these](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3522067/what-does-the-symbol-mean-here-x-yz-inner-products?noredirect=1#comment7243318_3522067) conditions are true for this application. I tried to do them all but couldn't do iv):

[image]

[image]

1) Have I done i, ii and iii correctly?

2) Why are x and y represented like that instead of as vectors?

3) How do I do iv)?

4) Is y equal to the zero vector?

Answer (score 1):

Note that\begin{align}\bigl((x_1,x_2,x_3)|(x_1,x_2,x_3)\bigr)&=2{x_1}^2+{x_2}^2-2x_2x_3+3{x_3}^2\\&=2{x_1}^2+(x_2-x_3)^2+2{x_3}^2.\end{align}This proves that $\bigl((x_1,x_2,x_3)|(x_1,x_2,x_3)\bigr)\geqslant0$ and that $\bigl((x_1,x_2,x_3)|(x_1,x_2,x_3)\bigr)=0$ if and only if $x_1=x_2=x_3=0$ .

Comment: I don't quite understand what I have to prove here, if x is the null vector or if it is greater or equal than zero?

Comment: Also why not $x_1^2+x_2^2+x_3^2$?

Comment: For any vector $x$, I proved two things: that $(x,x)\geqslant0$ and that $(x,x)=0$ if and only if $x=(0,0,0)$.

Comment: Why should it be ${x_1}^2+{x_2}^2+{x_3}^2$?

Comment: Because that's a more obvious answer for $((x_1,x_2,x_3),(x_1,x_2,x_3))$

Comment: It turns out that $\bigl((x_1,x_2,x_3),(x_1,x_2,x_3)\bigr)=2{x_1}^2+{x_2}^2-2x_2x_3+3{x_3}^2$. Why is it “obvious” that this is equal to ${x_1}^2+{x_2}^2+{x_3}^2$? I hope it isn't obvious, since that's actually false.

Comment: That's how I have been doing the dot product so far... here I'd do $x_1*x_1+x_2*x_2+x_3*x_3= {x_1}^2+{x_2}^2+{x_3}^2$.

Comment: Why? You are supposed to use the product given by the problem.

Comment: I'm not given $(x|x)$ here though...

Comment: Aren't you supposed to prove that the map $(x,y)\mapsto(x|y)$ is an inner product?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/103715/discussion-between-silenceonthewire-and-jose-carlos-santos).